# Can somebody please explain ruby constant lookup for me?

Tags: ruby, constants

More specifically:

- When do you need to prefix the scope with `::` (like `::Foo::Bar`)
- When is directly referring to a scoped const ok? (just `Foo::Bar`)
- Is there a good reason why this behavior is so confusing?

EDIT: I am talking about stuff like this

```
module Foo
  THING = 'thing'
  module Bar
    puts THING
  end
end
#=> thing

module Foo::Bar
  puts THING
end
#=> NameError: uninitialized constant Foo::Bar::THING
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> When do you need to prefix the scope
>   with :: (like ::Foo::Bar)

When there's another constant with the same name in the current namespace.

> When is directly referring to a scoped
>   const ok? (just Foo::Bar)

When there isn't another constant with the same name in the current namespace. Ie. when that identifier is unambiguous. Similarly, you could just use `Bar` to aid readability if it was unambiguous.

> Is there a good reason why this
>   behavior is so confusing?

It's balancing readability and ease of use against specificity. You don't always want to have to do `::Foo::Bar::Baz::Boo` (the globally unique identifier) when you're deep down in your namespace.

Comment: Your second example only brings the Foo::Bar namespace into scope. OTOH, when you open each namespace explicitly--as in your first example--both Foo and Foo::Bar are brought into scope.

Comment: That is pretty odd, but would explain it. I assumed it would search in all modules leading up to the class in either syntax. do you know of any other differences between  the two syntaxes?

Comment: I think I understand it's not necessary to prefix if those constants are unique throughout my whole Rails App… Does this mean if so I don't need to prefix at all? Does it mean ALL modules/classes will be "scanned"?

Comment: It just scans the current namespace. You're only ever in the global namespace unless you've "opened" a namespace using the `module` keyword. So, if the top of your file says `class Foo::Bar` (where Foo is a module) your class definition will be in the global/root namespace. But, if you say `module Foo; class Bar;` your class definition will be in the Foo namespace and you can reference `Foo::Baz` with simply `Baz`.

Answer (score 0):

In as far as I've understood/experienced it: when in a module/class `Foo`, then `Bar` refers to `Foo::Bar` unless it doesn't exist -- in which case it means `::Bar`.)

Please take it with a grain of salt, though, because I'm new to ruby as well. :-P